# How do I enable cloud sync?

Tags: steam

I'm trying to upload a mission to the Workshop, but I need to enable cloud sync before I can. How do I do this?

Comment: I don't believe the game itself matters, so I've removed the tag.  If it does, though, feel free to add it back in.

Comment: I added that tag because I want to upload that mission to this game. So if there would be needed what game I am using. Then it is self-explained in the tag section. (Readded)

Comment: The point is that how to do it isn't specific to the game.  For Arqade, there's no reason to include the tag, because it doesn't change for every game.  It's the same for all Steam games.

Comment: Very well, as you may point out; I have no knowledge of Steam Cloud

Answer (score 3):

Open settings, click "Cloud", check "Enable Steam Cloud synchronization for applications which support it".